# How to force powershell to refresh cached data? Get-ChildItem results for PSDrive not current

Tags: iis, powershell

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$pool = "ChannelServices"
$wp = Get-ChildItem "IIS:\AppPools\$pool\WorkerProcesses"
Get-Process -Id $wp.processId
Restart-WebAppPool $pool
sleep 5
Get-ChildItem "IIS:\AppPools\$pool\WorkerProcesses"
Get-Process -Id $wp.processId
```

So when I do a Get-ChildItem for the WorkerProcesses of a particular AppPool, then restart that AppPool, I should get a new PID, which I do.  However, rerunning Get-ChildItem still shows the old PID.  If I close Powershell and reopen, it will not show the correct new PID.

How can I force Powershell to clear it's cache, or whatever is holding onto that incorrect information...

[image: Shows how Get-ChildItem is not updating with the new PID.]

**UPDATE**
Just to be clear, my question is how can I clear the local cache when using the IIS PSDrive.

I noticed the TypeName: Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement#workerProcesses#workerProcess

Has a method:
Name              MemberType            Definition
----              ----------            ----------
ClearLocalData    Method                void ClearLocalData()

But it hasn't really worked for me...   Like someone below stated, this might just be a bug.

I see answers below on how to use WMI, which I'm aware of.

@theJasonHelmick provided a good one:

```
GWMI win32_process -filter "name='w3wp.exe'" | Select Name, ProcessId, @{n='AppPool';e={$_.GetOwner().user}}
```

That gives me the Username the AppPool is running under.  I modified that a bit to pull the actual apppool name from the CommandLine:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_process -filter "name='w3wp.exe'" | Select Name, ProcessId, @{n='AppPool';e={($_.CommandLine).Split("`"")[1]}}
```

Comment: Or if someone knows a better way to get the PID for a particular AppPool, that might be helpful as well.
End goal is that I want to recycle AppPools one at a time.
I have 40 plus Application Pools, and if they recycle at the same time, I get issues with Memory.   I want to recycle one, and then wait until the old PID terminates before moving on to the next AppPool.

Comment: Have you tried `$wp.Refresh()` instead of redoing Get-ChildItem?

Comment: There is actually a ClearLocalData method when I check Get-Member.  However, trying $wp.ClearLocalData() I get the following error...
Exception calling "ClearLocalData" with "0" argument(s): "The configuration object is read only, because it has been 
committed by a call to ServerManager.CommitChanges(). If write access is required, use ServerManager to get a new 
reference."
At line:1 char:1
+ $wp.ClearLocalData()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 3):

I could reproduce this behavior on IIS 8.5, it looks like a bug to me.

Using WMI worked for me in the same PowerShell session where Get-ChildItem returned the out-dated PID

```
(gwmi -NS 'root\WebAdministration' -class 'WorkerProcess' | ? AppPoolName -eq $pool | Select -First 1).ProcessId
```

This returned the correct pid for the first WorkerProcess

Comment: @RyanRies - where did I say I was unable to reproduce the behaviour. I wrote 'I could reproduce...'. To be clear I used Get-ChildItem in PowerShell to return the pid, then recycled the pool and still got the old pid, that's when I started looking for a way to clear that cache and when I couldn't find one, I looked for a different way to get the pid.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your post.

Comment: Not working $wp.Refresh(), Get-ChildItem, $wp.ClearLocalData() in IIS 8.5?

Comment: @Kiquenet - both Refresh and ClearLocalData are not valid methods for $wp which is of type `Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement`

Answer (score 3):

If you need to refresh the cache of worker processes, you can just remove and import the Web Administration Module again.

```
Remove-Module WebAdministration
Import-Module WebAdministration
```

Probably not the best solution as the one utilizing WMI, but if for some reason you don't have access to the IIS WMI objects or can't install them, this will work.

Comment: This solution works. Tested it also with "import-module webadministration -force" but that did not work. Upvoted because the solution is easy to remember, does not involve recycling pools or restarting my powershell (which is in a way also removing and importing that specific module). (did not test it on various OS versions / Powershell versions)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm totally missing something, I'm guessing that you storing the first get-process in the variable `$wp` then referencing the variable again will return the old data?

What if you do either of:

- the second time running `get-childitem` again store in `$wp` (overwriting the value)?
- erase the variable before using it again:

  remove-variable `wp`
- store the second `get-childitem` in a variable with a totally different name?

I'm a big fan of `remove-variable` myself, as old values really can give rise to unexpected weirdnesses.

---

**[EDIT]**
The answer of Peter Hahndorf seems to be the alternative endorsed by Microsoft, though I have now misplaced the link for that. But as the cause of the behaviour indeed seems to be a possible bug, I'll just complement with the following:

[This guy](http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2011/07/28/Recycling-an-Application-Pool-with-C-(Part-2).aspx) seems to have solved the problem of recycling application pools in a most efficient manner using C#. If speed is of essence (WMI is typically on the time consuming side), such as if one must do a large number of recycles in a short time frame, this could be worth looking at.

It looks not too hard to port the solution to Powershell, if one just loads the `%WinDir%\system32\Inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll` into the shell first to access the namespace.

The original reference point for the code seems to come from Microsoft [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2006/04/17/microsoftwebadministration.aspx).

Comment: - Line 3 stores Get-ChildItem output from the AppPool into $wp  
- Line 5 shows that output with the PID being 756  
- Line 7 queries Get-Process for PID 756 and shows it is found.  
- Line 9 Restarts the AppPool, effectively killing PID 756.  
- Line 12 Reruns Get-Childitem, the output should show a different PID, however it still shows PID 756 running.  This is where the problem is.  It should show a NEW PID.  
- Line 14 Again queries Get-Process for PID 756 and shows it not found.  Which is correct.

Comment: Dang..  How do I add Line Breaks?

Comment: Oh, and just to be clear, the error text on not finding PID 756 is good.  The problem is that Get-ChildItem **DOES** find it.

Comment: Ok, just for problem isolation: what happens if you run the second get-childitem in another shell instance?

Comment: As long as I haven't already queried that pool, it properly shows the new PID in a new shell.  Also notice in the original image, that the second Get-ChildItem does not show Handles or a Start Time, which is odd...

Comment: I have to see if I get the same problem myself (which I probably do) in a couple of hours. I am thinking maybe it's coming from a .NET instance behind the shell itself in that case.

Comment: Confirmed on IIS 7 with PS 2.0. Really curious behaviour for sure. The IIS team proposes the wmi solution as an alternative, but I also found a C# solution calling an IIS .NET assembly which seemed really neat and fast. It is probably not too hard to port to PS, if speed is a key factor. Now I stupidly closed my computer but will edit that link in tomorrow just in case someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 1):

*Answering an old question as this is the top thing in a Google search for my problem, and does not have my solution.*

I am watching a file for updates and using Get-ChildItem to get a reference to it.

```
$output = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File $file | Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.LastWriteTime -gt $DateNow)}
```

I simply repeat the line above every time I want to refresh $output

While I know the file is increasing in size, $output.length would stick.  It would be fine if I hit F5 in the directory.

Using $output.refresh refreshed the object without needing to re-assign it.

Comment: $output may not be a file object, it may be an array of file objects.  If so, $object.length is how many items in the array.